# Can a property be optional?

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have a small class:

```
Public Class LimitOrder
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="size")> _
    Public Property Size() As Double

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="price")> _
    Public Property Price() As Double

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="persistenceType")> _
    Public Property PersistenceType() As PersistenceType

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="betTargetType")>
    Public Property BetTargetType() As BetTargetType

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="betTargetSize")>
    Public Property BetTargetSize() As Double

End Class
```

My issue is if `BetTargetType` is given a value, then the Size property must not be passed to the processor.

Every time I initialise the class the `Size` property is included and given a value of `0.0`.

If I comment out (or omit) the `Size` property it works fine, but there will be cases where I want to include Size.

Ideally I would like the `Size` property to be optional, or two types of the class, one with the Size property and one without.

I have tried making the `Size` property nullable - but the value is created before serialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Private _Size As Double?

<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="size")>
Public Property Size() As Double?
    Get
        If BetTargetType IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return _Size
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Double?)
        _Size = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Like this `Size` returns `Nothing` if `BetTargetType` is not `Nothing`.